# Species Identification: Waterborne worm/larva, California, USA (and is it safe)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, limnology

Can you help ID this species? The photos are low quality, so I'll do my best to describe them.

I found them after I left a cup of dechlorinated, freshwater aquarium water outside with a plant in it, hoping the plant would grow better in sunlight. I do not think they came from the aquarium, but I might as well add it.

I left this cup on my second floor balcony. I don't know if this might narrow down the search, but whatever insect it is is somehow present on my roof (flying or climbing, I don't know).

They have a black head, are visibly segmented inside, but their outside is smooth, with no ridges. They are about 3-5mm long (I think based on age). I put them on a bit of cardboard paper to take the photos, and as the paper dried it appears that they need water or at least a moist surface to survive.

[image: Them, on a cardboard-paper thing]
[image]